# Asking about the university courses

Tags: questions, phrase-requests

What is the correct way to ask another person about the course he is doing/pursuing at a college or university?

> What course are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What course are you doing?

or

> What course are you taking?

or

> What course are you studying?

or

> What course are you enrolled in?

---

Google Counts:

- "what course are you doing" university: 70K
- "what course are you taking" university: 20K
- "what course are you studying" university: 20K
- "what course are you enrolled in" university: 1.5K

Comment: do 'courses' mean subjects or course title as such?

Comment: Can I say MSc Engg as a course? or should I say networks, databases as courses?

Comment: Good question. I'd say that MSc. Software Engineering, for example, would in general be called a course. Networks, databases, etc. would in general be called subjects, modules or disciplines.

Comment: coming to modules, should I say what modules you have

Comment: @Dusty: when you say courses, it sounds like modules in the context  that you used,  to me. Please correct me.

Comment: @JPro - Yeah, I misread `course` as `courses`=`classes` which I assume is the same as `modules`.  Ignore the prior comment.

Comment: @Dusty: after I read your comment about "taking a course", I googled the phrase. You were actually right (see google counts).

Comment: @Bruno - Well, it sounded really odd to `do a course` where course was a class.  But once I realized my mistake, I could imagine it working where `course` is more akin to `major` or `path`.  If you search the plural which I think is more likely to have the `class` meaning, the counts reverse (44.5k for `taking`, 30k for `doing`) which still indicates `doing` works for that context as well. However, the links seem to be predominantly UK based, so combined with the fact that I'd never heard it used like that, I'll stick with it being a regional thing.  You learn something new every day here =D

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this one will vary depending on where you want to ask it.

"What course are you doing?" would certainly be fine in the UK, but US universities typically don't impose such rigid course structures, and I believe you'd be better off asking: "What's your major?"

Comment: In fact, I tend to use "course" merely as a synonym for "class". I'd interpret "What course are you taking?" as asking about my class schedule for the current semester. If phrased as "What course are you doing?", though, I'd probably make the connection that this is Brit-speak for "What's your major?".

Answer (score 1):

At certain universities, the correct question would be

> What are you reading?

Comment: Only in a formal setting, and only as long as the person wasn't looking at a book at the time...

Comment: This is not something we say in the US. "What is your major?" or "What are you studying?" is what we say here.

Comment: "What's your discipline?" is common in India.